WSL docker compose volume bind mount empty on host
I have Gitea on WSL as a docker container:
version: "3"

services:
  server:
    image: gitea/gitea:latest
    container_name: gitea
    mem_reservation: "1G"
    mem_limit: "1G"
    environment:
      - USER_UID=1000
      - USER_GID=1000
      - GITEA__database__DB_TYPE=mysql
      - GITEA__database__HOST=192.168.1.8:3306
      - GITEA__database__NAME=gitea
      - GITEA__database__USER=gitea
      - GITEA__database__PASSWD=xxxxxxxxxxx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /container_data/gitea:/data
    ports:
      - "32785:3000"
      - "32786:22"

I started the container just fine, then I did docker cp to copy the contents of the old container to the new one in a new host.
I can access the gitea website just fine and everything seems to work fine.
Why if I have the folder /container_data/gitea mounted to /data and there are files inside /data in the container do I not see the files from the host's side.
/docker-compose/gitea$ ll /container_data/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 daviid root 4096 May 21 08:48 ./
drwxr-xr-x 21 root    root 4096 May 21 08:58 ../
drwxrwxrwx  2 daviid root 4096 May 21 09:34 gitea/
drwxrwx---  5 daviid root 4096 May 20 12:03 mantisbt/
drwxrwx---  6 daviid root 4096 May 20 12:12 openfire/


/docker-compose/gitea$ ll /container_data/gitea/
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 2 daviid root 4096 May 21 09:34 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 daviid root 4096 May 21 08:48 ../

Container Inspect:
[
    {
        "Id": "d806d76443af75cce50bbe2ef559f3379d2a74c70ecca7fe9e6d7ca21af920a6",
        "Created": "2024-05-21T07:54:54.233863459Z",
        "Path": "/usr/bin/entrypoint",
        "Args": [
            "/bin/s6-svscan",
            "/etc/s6"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 35674,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2024-05-21T07:54:54.664974724Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:f6f6f2bec18fd00fe87e22836e26098b2c93e7637de937584c209579164e6c87",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/containers/d806d76443af75cce50bbe2ef559f3379d2a74c70ecca7fe9e6d7ca21af920a6/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/containers/d806d76443af75cce50bbe2ef559f3379d2a74c70ecca7fe9e6d7ca21af920a6/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/containers/d806d76443af75cce50bbe2ef559f3379d2a74c70ecca7fe9e6d7ca21af920a6/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/containers/d806d76443af75cce50bbe2ef559f3379d2a74c70ecca7fe9e6d7ca21af920a6/d806d76443af75cce50bbe2ef559f3379d2a74c70ecca7fe9e6d7ca21af920a6-json.log",
        "Name": "/gitea",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/container_data/gitea:/data:rw"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "gitea_default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "22/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "32786"
                    }
                ],
                "3000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "32785"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "always",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": [],
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 1073741824,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "MemoryReservation": 1073741824,
            "MemorySwap": 2147483648,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/951792a04261c849eb65f79c32d4f0d73c93133eccc3633bfa59d69441846afb-init/diff:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/c525dae1393fca0e097b35ee561909c0e4b5fc8a50e6a6caeb7a3093a2da82b2/diff:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/e2d5d474942cd0a2d61b63232c7c56d3fdc7069156745342a821071d26d56de0/diff:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/4acb1eb9c7b6560190ac7bd2659174a34d1d374917042bb552cd454e4772e0ba/diff:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/a82586d97010d85b754c753b7178fa343cfe07eafebb29e6a35810410d20bb6f/diff:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/4509ae18dfb896e1a3612006c047179d555f1f69164adcd01fa4e525c2e7862a/diff:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/d598e795d85239ea8fa262657019f7001d5319e5a4428af0c3a52a5288c35bb8/diff:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/51a201b1933e726d0f0d3f1c53429c929262e45ab0cdb61434ba4623db4f09a5/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/951792a04261c849eb65f79c32d4f0d73c93133eccc3633bfa59d69441846afb/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/951792a04261c849eb65f79c32d4f0d73c93133eccc3633bfa59d69441846afb/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/951792a04261c849eb65f79c32d4f0d73c93133eccc3633bfa59d69441846afb/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/container_data/gitea",
                "Destination": "/data",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "d806d76443af",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "22/tcp": {},
                "3000/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "GITEA__database__DB_TYPE=mysql",
                "GITEA__database__HOST=192.168.1.8:3306",
                "GITEA__database__NAME=gitea",
                "GITEA__database__USER=gitea",
                "GITEA__database__PASSWD=xxxxxxxxxx",
                "USER_UID=1000",
                "USER_GID=1000",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "USER=git",
                "GITEA_CUSTOM=/data/gitea"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/s6-svscan",
                "/etc/s6"
            ],
            "Image": "gitea/gitea:latest",
            "Volumes": {
                "/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/usr/bin/entrypoint"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "4ecb4de774f677923b279717eb2f375b0ec478cc2c0019f461cee168866513b4",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.depends_on": "",
                "com.docker.compose.image": "sha256:f6f6f2bec18fd00fe87e22836e26098b2c93e7637de937584c209579164e6c87",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "gitea",
                "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "/docker-compose/gitea/docker-compose.yml",
                "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "/docker-compose/gitea",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "server",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "2.20.3",
                "maintainer": "maintainers@gitea.io",
                "org.opencontainers.image.created": "2024-03-25T23:53:52.699Z",
                "org.opencontainers.image.description": "Git with a cup of tea! Painless self-hosted all-in-one software development service, including Git hosting, code review, team collaboration, package registry and CI/CD",
                "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "MIT",
                "org.opencontainers.image.revision": "d6b0d0e9c0108f1c6c84a2b14020b2529e5329b2",
                "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea",
                "org.opencontainers.image.title": "gitea",
                "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea",
                "org.opencontainers.image.version": "1"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "b4ae31c62b924f7afe2c10e1a35819adfab566bf6c54a49d43304a2144290425",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "22/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "32786"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "32786"
                    }
                ],
                "3000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "32785"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "32785"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/run/snap.docker/netns/b4ae31c62b92",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "gitea_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "gitea",
                        "server",
                        "d806d76443af"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "3a36acb52d5e3273e7e7850cd42f414b72b72b0de0bd2f14c124ea89f0ab510f",
                    "EndpointID": "b72b3d8099c43981a6fd7ccba1be4f46a12b301a90e2b498ec87590fcc6708d6",
                    "Gateway": "172.21.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.21.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:15:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]

I also have a jenkins container in which I did the same but I forgot to create /container_data/jenkins and it still runs fine.
Where is my stuff actually being stored?
